# Как отправить сообщение в Viber и какова предварительная процедура для такой возможности?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть необходимость отсылать клиентам сообщение в вайбере - напоминание. Я так понял, что нет открытого API для реализации этой идеи? Какие есть варианты и предоставляет ли Viber такую возможность?

Answer (score 2):

Как это нет?)) Документация по Rest API:

https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/

---

Теперь используйте в c#.
Пример: https://github.com/edanila/viber.bot

### Пример теста с репозитория изложенного выше

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Viber.Bot.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Viber bot integration test.
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Viber API.
        /// </summary>
        private IViberBotClient _viberBotClient;

        private string _authToken;
        private string _webhookUrl;
        private string _adminId;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            _authToken = config["authToken"];
            _webhookUrl = config["webhookUrl"];
            _adminId = config["adminId"];

            _viberBotClient = new ViberBotClient(_authToken);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetAccountInfoAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.GetAccountInfoAsync();
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [Priority(1)]
        public async Task SetWebhookAsync()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SetWebhookAsync(_webhookUrl);
            return;
        }

        //[TestMethod]
        public async Task GetUserDetailsAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.GetUserDetailsAsync(_adminId);
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendTextMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(new TextMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Text = "Hi!:)"
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendPictureMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendPictureMessageAsync(new PictureMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Media = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Viber-logo.png"
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendContactMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendContactMessageAsync(new ContactMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = "Brad Pitt",
                    TN = "+0123456789"
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendFileMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendFileMessageAsync(new FileMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Media = "http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3",
                FileName = "audio.mp3",
                Size = 443926
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendLocationMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendLocationMessageAsync(new LocationMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Location = new Location
                {
                    Lon = 1,
                    Lat = -2
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendStickerMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendStickerMessageAsync(new StickerMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                StickerId = "40108"
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendVideoMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendVideoMessageAsync(new VideoMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Media = "https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-files/blob/master/big_buck_bunny.mp4?raw=true",
                Size = 5510872
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendUrlMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendUrlMessageAsync(new UrlMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Media = "https://www.google.com"
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendKeyboardMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendKeyboardMessageAsync(new KeyboardMessage
            {
                Receiver = _adminId,
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Text = "Test keyboard",
                Keyboard = new Keyboard
                {
                    Buttons = new[]
                    {
                        new KeyboardButton
                        {
                            Text = "Button 1",
                            ActionBody = "AB1"
                        }
                    }
                },
                TrackingData = "td"
            });
            return;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task SendBroadcastMessageAsyncTest()
        {
            var result = await _viberBotClient.SendBroadcastMessageAsync(new BroadcastMessage
            {
                Sender = new UserBase
                {
                    Name = "Smbdy"
                },
                Text = "Broadcast message!:)",
                BroadcastList = new []
                {
                    _adminId
                }
            });
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал перенести из репозитория код, ключевую часть. Сегодня репа есть - завтра нет. А в остальном - гуд, плюсанул.

Comment: @AK к сожалению кода слишком много)

Comment: Проблема с переносом - перенес, АПИ поменялось, придется самому поддерживать и перепиливать. Лучше форкнуть и следить за родительским репозиторием. Или вообще взяться за поддержку основного репо

Comment: В общем, если есть необходимость рассылать в вайбере сообщения, то услуга платная - предоставляет сам вайбер. Данный пример  - это пример чат-бота и количество сообщений ограничено, я бы сказал, что это кострированный вариант